# GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

This has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841211/googleplayservicesutil-geterrordialog-does-nothing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099005/android-googleplayservicesutil-geterrordialog-does-not-show-the-dialog), but there are not useful answers, so I'll try to be specific: I'm trying to implement Google Cloud Messaging on an app developed using Android Studio 1.2.2. I have installed Google Play Services as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), and I implemented the `checkPlayServices()` method as suggested in [this sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/81c831d85a67157746009fa2df81a683f860d21e/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MainActivity.java#L92):

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If the device doesn't has Google Play Service or if it is outdated this method should alert the user and provide a button to install/update it easily. I test the app on a Samsung Galaxy S II with Android 4.1.2 with factory settings so it doesn't has an updated Google Play Services. I have confirmed that the `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()` method is called, but the dialog doesn't appear. Instead I got the following in the logcat:

```
06-14 19:19:45.691  10616-10616/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
06-14 19:19:45.691  10616-10616/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 250: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
06-14 19:19:45.691  10616-10616/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00c2
06-14 19:19:45.691  10616-10616/? I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: access denied from Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil; to field Landroid/app/Notification;.extras
06-14 19:19:45.691  10616-10616/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve instance field 18
06-14 19:19:45.691  10616-10616/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x00e1
06-14 19:19:45.691  10616-10616/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
06-14 19:19:45.691  10616-10616/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 27 (Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
06-14 19:19:45.691  10616-10616/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000e
06-14 19:19:45.696  10616-10616/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh
06-14 19:19:45.696  10616-10616/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 542: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
06-14 19:19:45.696  10616-10616/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
06-14 19:19:45.696  10616-10616/? W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 2012110
```

I'm completely stuck. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dialog is not being displayed because execution in the UI thread does not suspend when a dialog is created. This means your application will continue to run after the dialog is supposed to be displayed. If your code does something such as:

```
showDialog();
startDifferentActivity();
```

A user wouldn't be able to interact with the dialog because the different activity would start before the dialog even displayed. If you have code execution that is dependent on the user selecting the positive/negative/neutral buttons of a dialog or dismissing a dialog, implement the appropriate listeners.

Comment: I just tried what you suggested but I get the same bunch of error. It starts with `I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza` and ends with `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 7571000 but found 2012110`.

Comment: What does your code do after it returns? Does the app crash? You say that the method `getErrorDialog()` is called but does not appear. This could be because when a dialog is shown, execution in the UI thread does not suspend while waiting for the user to interact with the dialog. This means your function returns and execution continues, so if you were to do something like create a dialog and then start a new activity, the dialog would never appear because your new activity would start.

Comment: Can you edit your answer? It is what described in the previous comment what worked. Thanks a lot!